# Are there any web scrapers that cannot be detected as bots by websites?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm creating a web scraper using python and selenium and I have noticed that chrome can understand when a bot is used to scan to scan the web instead of a human. I'm also guessing that some websites wont allow bots to scan through their websites, like for example airline companies, which is inconvenient

Is there a way to create a web scraper that cannot be identified as a bot?

Comment: One technique that web servers use to [try to] identify bots is to examine the origin of the request (IP address). Use of proxies can help to overcome this

Answer (score 0):

'Web scrapper' is a broad term, but if you want to get and/or post data to a webpage, you have two libraries designed for that: [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/). Between those I recommend requests.

Also, [BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) can be very helpfull.

Comment: What about selenium?

Comment: The thing is selenium was designed to do testing, so it has lots of stuff above retrieving data from a webpage. It basically recreates the behavior of a human with what is called a webdriver. I understand that it may seem easier to use, but it is very far from being the ideal tool to do web scrapping

Comment: Ok I understand, I will work with requests.
What about bot detection of the above libraries? Are requests, httpx and beautifulsoup4 undetectable? How about selenium?

Comment: @Luis: That's just partly correct. Most websites heavily rely on Javascript and XHR requests, in these cases a simple http library cant do much.